# How can I merge two ListMaps with the order of elements retained?

Tags: scala

Say we have two `ListMap`s:

```
val m1 = new ListMap() + ("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
val m2 = new ListMap() + ("c" -> 3, "b" -> 0)
```

I want to merge them, preferring the values in the second map. I want the order of the final `ListMap` to retain the order of elements, from first to last, and from first map to second -- but -- preferring the order of the first map when a conflict arises. The result of ordering the maps above should look like:

```
ListMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 3)
```

These solutions do *not* work, and are *not* what I'm looking for:

```
m1 + ("c" -> 3) + ("b" -> 0)
res2: immutable.ListMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 0)

m1 ++ m2
res3: immutable.ListMap[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 0)
```

Comment: The result should prefer the values of the second map, but the order of the first.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `map` and a `filter`ing operation:

```
def merge[A, B](m1: Map[A, B], m2: Map[A, B]): Map[A, B] = {
  // Retain k, v ordering from m1, replacing the v with m2's v if appropriate
  m1.map { 
      case (k, v) => k -> m2.getOrElse(k, v) 
  } ++ 
  // Append the elements in m2 which aren't in m1
  m2.filterKeys(!m1.keySet(_))
}
```

which yields

```
scala> merge(m1, m2)
res17: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 3)
```